# wxStringProperty not consuming key down events

Tags: event-handling, wxwidgets

I am creating an editor using wxWidgets and handle key down events in the wxApplication-derived class.  However, when I have a wxStringProperty focused by the user, the key presses are still handled by the application event handler.  For example, if I press DELETE to delete a character in the string property text field, the event handler receives that DELETE key down event.

How do I make the wxStringProperty consume all key down events when it is focused so that the app doesn't receive any?

Comment: Have you tried inserting `event.Skip()` in your custom event handler?

Comment: The application event handler does event.Skip().  I think the wxStringProperty is not receiving the key event.  The application handler is definitely receiving the event and then I skip it.  But the key I press it not showing up in the text field of the wxStringProperty.

Comment: If there's a cursor flashing in the wxStringProperty, it should be the focused widget right?  Then it should receive any keydown events before the application?  It looks like it's bypassing the wxStringProperty and being handled directly by the application.  event.Skip() does nothing.

Comment: Very strange. According to `http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_processing` the application-level handler should be the last to receive the event. As a very dirty solution, you could (from the app handler) get a pointer to the active cell editor with `wxPropertyGrid::GetEditorTextCtrl` and send him the event again with the `QueueEvent()` method.

Comment: I thought so too.  The way I got round it is to handle the keydown event on all my sub-windows and remove the handler from the application.

Comment: Glad to see you found a way out. I had similar problems with `wxGrid`, it's really difficult to understand how the events are processed because the cell editors are created at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, my property editors are created at runtime too.  I wish wxWidgets had a method to see where the events went.